# how to access server resource for login page and home page when authentication mode is set to forms and protection is set to All

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

In my asp.net application ,in web.config file i have set authentication mode="forms" and protection="All".But after doing this i get access to login page without any image and css resources .I also need to access my home page without login.How can i do this kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config, you will need to add a location that allows all user to access the images and CSS files. Something like:

```
<location path="images">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

That should sit under the root node  of the config file.

You can do the same for the homepage, adjusting the value of path to the correct location.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, you should mark as answered.